# Get the PK of GET Var Upon Submission of Django Form

Tags: python, mysql, django, insert, crud

I'm currently trying to insert into `PathsOfDomain` for `pathToScan, FKtoTld` fields. The problem is, I want to be able to grab the `id` field from `Tld` table for the submitted value (see `view` below) and then submit that with the `dbInsert` var. The problem is `EnteredDomain` var below is the value being entered for `DomainNm` column in `Tld` table.

How can I get just the `id` of the row in `Tld` and include it with the `dbInsert` ?

I have two tables:

```
class Tld(models.Model):
    domainNm = models.CharField(verbose_name="",max_length=40,unique=True,validators=[RegexValidator('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}$','format: domain.com only','Invalid Entry')])
    FKtoClient = models.ForeignKey(User)  

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.domainNm) 

class PathsOfDomain(models.Model):
    pathToScan = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #urlHttpResponse = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
    FKtoTld = models.ForeignKey(Tld) # [id] from Tld table
```

I have a Django `View`:

```
def Processinitialscan(request):
    # mechanize options here 
    EnteredDomain = request.GET.get('domainNm')

    GetEnteredDomainObjects = Tld.objects.get(DomainNm=EnteredDomain)

    EnteredDomainRowID = GetEnteredDomainObjects.objects.get(pk=GetEnteredDomainObjects)
```

`EnteredDomain` value might look like - `site.com`

**I have a loop :** in a class that is imported in the `view` above.

```
for url in urls:
            mb.open(url)    # mechanize opens each url in urls[]
            beautifulSoupObj = BeautifulSoup(mb.response().read())  #beautifulsoup reads in the mechanize response

            elements = beautifulSoupObj.select("h3.r a")    #get just the elements we want

            #for each element found, insert the 'href' value for pathToScan Field and include
                #PK value (id) field from the submitted domain in table [Tld] into PathsOfDomain - FkToTld field.
                #finally, save this all()
            for element in elements:
                #print(i.attrs["href"])  
                dbInsert = PathsOfDomain(pathToScan=element.attrs["href"],FKtoTld=EnteredDomainRowID)
                dbInsert.save()
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Above code is currently throwing error:
**Manager isn't accessible via Tld instances**
I think because of this line:

```
EnteredDomainRowID = GetEnteredDomainObjects.objects.get(pk=GetEnteredDomainObjects)
```

Comment: Are you using Django models?  Those will be more helpful than a schema diagram

Comment: What is `urls`?  Have you inspected any of the variables to see where it goes wrong?  How do you get to the loop from the view?  ...etc.  Nothing is obviously wrong that I can see, so it's probably a part of the code you haven't shown us - and it looks like there's a lot you haven't shown us.

Comment: `PathToTldFKId` is also never defined

Comment: urls[] is defined within a file urldata.py which is included in the views.py is.

Comment: The portion: FKtoTld=PathToTldFKId, should be the PK id found from the domainNm. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please see updated code for the view

Comment: Also please see the updated dbInsert var too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Manager isn't accessible via Tld instances

You're right about where the cause is:

```
GetEnteredDomainObjects = Tld.objects.get(DomainNm=EnteredDomain)

EnteredDomainRowID = GetEnteredDomainObjects.objects.get(pk=GetEnteredDomainObjects)
```

`GetEnteredDomainObjects` is an instance of `Tld`, so `objects` isn't accessible.

If you're trying to get the primary key off of it, it's simply:

```
EnteredDomainRowID = GetEnteredDomainObjects.pk
```

Comment: How can I make EnteredDomainRowID available to a separate class file (urlsdata.py) ?

Comment: I know I can pass variables from view->template, but how about from a class file, to a view?

Comment: Please specify, I know its newbish.

Comment: How do I import the views.py into urldata.py class?

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could help me here.

Comment: @CodeTalk [Information on modules and `import`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should really give your fields better names. There's no reason to use that abbreviated format. And note that the Django field that you have named "FkToTLD" is represented as an actual TLD object, so is better just called `TLD`. Plus, field names as well as local variables should have `lower_case_with_underscore` format.

Your question itself is hard to understand. If you have want to get a TLD object from a domain name, you can just look it up:

```
domain = TLD.objects.get(DomainNm=entered_domain)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to get the PK-id Tld(id) value e.g. 1, 6, 36 .. any numeric value. And include this value when I submit the form - using this variable - dbInsert

Comment: I currently am getting the value of the domainNm but not the ID . Does that clarify?

Comment: Based on your code for 'domain' how can I only access the [id] of this tld object?

Comment: I would appreciate any further recommendations on django conventions you might be able to suggest